# how to remove the thousand separator using cultureinfo?

Tags: c#, winforms, formatting, string-formatting, cultureinfo

I try to remove the thousand separator so I'm experimenting some code, but it throws and exception. I tried with `Convert.ToDouble`, `Convert.ToDecimal` etc.

it says:

> Convert.ToDouble("1.234,45") threw and exception of 'System.FormatException'

The conversion is thrown from line : `Convert.ToDouble()`

The argument `n2` uses the culturinfo, but I also tried "0.00" both throws the same exception

The whole idea is : how to remove the thousand separator, my input is always in this format: 1.234,54 (comma as decimal and dot as thousand separator)... I like to use it in Textbox GotFocus Event.. so the format should be shown like 12345,45

so : 1.254,45 should be 1254,45 and 1.254,00 should be 1254,00

```
 //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("NL-be");
NumberFormatInfo nfi = (NumberFormatInfo)ci.NumberFormat.Clone();
//Now force thousand separator to be empty string
nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = "";
//Format decimal number to 2 decimal places
string decimalFormatted = Convert.ToDouble("1.234,45").ToString("0.00", nfi);
string decimalFormatted = Convert.ToDouble("1.234,45").ToString("n2", nfi);
```

Comment: For invariant culture: `Convert.ToDouble("1.234,45", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` else: `Convert.ToDouble("1.234,45", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-gb"))`

Comment: both code of lines gives the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specify the culture with conversion and it will work like:

```
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("NL-be");
double d = Convert.ToDouble("1.234,45", ci);
```

Comment: thanks this code was working for me. but how does it work? because NL-be has thousand separator a DOT so it should still show the dot.?

Comment: "@ Habib": I just see an issue: 
the rule is everything after the comma is a decimal, everything works fine except #1 situation: if I type 1234,00 and leave (it makes: or 123.400,00) and when I type 1234,56 it makes 123.456,00)... so when I use comma as decimal the result is not good... if I type 1234.56 it makes 1.234,56 which is good. So how can I fix 1234,56. it should not make 123.456,00 but it should make 1.234,56. and also type 12,34 becomes 1234,00. please advice?

Comment: `using System.Globalization;`

Answer (score 3):

Your calls to `Convert.ToDouble` don't specify a format at all. You need to remember that this:

```
string decimalFormatted = Convert.ToDouble("1.234,45").ToString("n2", nfi);
```

is equivalent to:

```
double tmp = string decimalFormatted = Convert.ToDouble("1.234,45");
string decimalFormatted = tmp.ToString("n2", nfi);
```

It's the first line that's failing, not the second... and in the first line, it's just going to use the current thread culture.

I suggest you use `Double.Parse` instead, and specify the format there. (You could use `Convert.ToDouble` instead, but I generally prefer the more type-specific `Double.Parse` etc calls. It means there's less to change if you move to `TryParse` etc.)

You should *also* consider using `decimal` instead of `double` if the exact digits matter. For example, if this is a currency value, it's logically more of a `decimal` number than a `double` number.